# Auto-indent in python-mode 6.2.0

Tags: python, emacs, indentation, python-mode

I recently updated python-mode to version 6.2.0 and the indentation behaviour became less efficient.
For instance, typing

```
try:
     something to try
     except SomeError:
```

used to correctly indent SomeError as soon as I typed  `:`. It does not work anymore. What did I break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize `py-electric-colon-active-p` to non-nil

Also `py-electric-colon-bobl-only` must be set to `nil` in this case - default is `t`

bobl stands for beginning of block

Comment: @AlfredM. py-electric-colon-bobl-only must be set to nil also - edited the answer.